# How to get mobile hamburger menu working in Rails 7 with Tailwind?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, ruby-on-rails-7

I ran this new setup for Rails 7 to include tailwind:

```
rails new hg -j esbuild --css tailwind --database=postgresql
```

This worked great it seemed when I grabbed this code from tailwindui.com:

```
<!-- This example requires Tailwind CSS v2.0+ -->
<div class="relative bg-gray-50 overflow-hidden">
  <div class="hidden sm:block sm:absolute sm:inset-y-0 sm:h-full sm:w-full" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="relative h-full max-w-7xl mx-auto">
      <svg class="absolute right-full transform translate-y-1/4 translate-x-1/4 lg:translate-x-1/2" width="404" height="784" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 404 784">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="f210dbf6-a58d-4871-961e-36d5016a0f49" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4" class="text-gray-200" fill="currentColor" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect width="404" height="784" fill="url(#f210dbf6-a58d-4871-961e-36d5016a0f49)" />
      </svg>
      <svg class="absolute left-full transform -translate-y-3/4 -translate-x-1/4 md:-translate-y-1/2 lg:-translate-x-1/2" width="404" height="784" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 404 784">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="5d0dd344-b041-4d26-bec4-8d33ea57ec9b" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4" class="text-gray-200" fill="currentColor" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>
        <rect width="404" height="784" fill="url(#5d0dd344-b041-4d26-bec4-8d33ea57ec9b)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="relative pt-6 pb-16 sm:pb-24">
    <div>
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">
        <nav class="relative flex items-center justify-between sm:h-10 md:justify-center" aria-label="Global">
          <div class="flex items-center flex-1 md:absolute md:inset-y-0 md:left-0">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full md:w-auto">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="sr-only">Workflow</span>
                <img class="h-8 w-auto sm:h-10" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg" alt="">
              </a>
              <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center md:hidden">
                <button type="button" class="bg-gray-50 rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                  <!-- Heroicon name: outline/menu -->
                  <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden md:flex md:space-x-10">
            <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Product</a>

            <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Features</a>

            <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Marketplace</a>

            <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Company</a>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden md:absolute md:flex md:items-center md:justify-end md:inset-y-0 md:right-0">
            <span class="inline-flex rounded-md shadow">
              <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-indigo-600 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50">
                Log in
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <!--
        Mobile menu, show/hide based on menu open state.

        Entering: "duration-150 ease-out"
          From: "opacity-0 scale-95"
          To: "opacity-100 scale-100"
        Leaving: "duration-100 ease-in"
          From: "opacity-100 scale-100"
          To: "opacity-0 scale-95"
      -->
      <div class="absolute z-10 top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden">
        <div class="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
          <div class="px-5 pt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
            <div>
              <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-600.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="-mr-2">
              <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                <span class="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                <!-- Heroicon name: outline/x -->
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3">
            <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Product</a>

            <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Features</a>

            <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Marketplace</a>

            <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Company</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="block w-full px-5 py-3 text-center font-medium text-indigo-600 bg-gray-50 hover:bg-gray-100">
            Log in
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <main class="mt-16 mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:mt-24">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl md:text-6xl">
          <span class="block xl:inline">Data to enrich your</span>
          <span class="block text-indigo-600 xl:inline">online business</span>
        </h1>
        <p class="mt-3 max-w-md mx-auto text-base text-gray-500 sm:text-lg md:mt-5 md:text-xl md:max-w-3xl">
          Anim aute id magna aliqua ad ad non deserunt sunt. Qui irure qui lorem cupidatat commodo. Elit sunt amet fugiat veniam occaecat fugiat aliqua.
        </p>
        <div class="mt-5 max-w-md mx-auto sm:flex sm:justify-center md:mt-8">
          <div class="rounded-md shadow">
            <a href="#" class="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10">
              Get started
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-3 rounded-md shadow sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
            <a href="#" class="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-indigo-600 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10">
              Live demo
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything seemed to work perfectly except the mobile menu part for every code sample I tried. The hamburger menu does not appear in mobile. I only get the "X" mark that does not work. My understanding was that the new Rails 7 setup with Tailwind was suppose to configure everything. But it appears this is not the case.

javascript.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/views/**/*.html.erb',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js'
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.9",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css"
  }
}
```

Anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with Rails, but rather that Tailwind does not come with javascript by default.

Here are a couple of solutions for you:

- If the responsive classes of Tailwind are not working, you should add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` to your `application.html.erb`
- If the "interactive" part is not working, you should either write your own javascript logic to handle it, use HeadlessUI (provided by Tailwind) or use AlpineJS. For Alpine, you can copy the code straight from TailwindUI examples via Developer Tools (Inspect Element).